# Websocket is not closed upon missing pong when connection is interrupted

Tags: websocket, dart

Websockets should be closed with WebSocketStatus.GOING_AWAY if no pong message is received within pingInterval. Why doesn't this work when connectivity is lost, e.g. with an un-plugged cable? Is this expected behaviour? And if so, what's the point of the ping messages? (I know of the TCP timeout stuff.)

Reproduce:

1. With a low pingInterval (e.g. 1ms), websocket is correctly closed with closeCode==1001
2. With a high pingInterval (e.g. 1000ms), kill connectivity after a while, websocket will not close (closeCode is null)

Here is the code to reproduce:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:web_socket_channel/io.dart';

void main() {
  final channel = IOWebSocketChannel.connect("ws://echo.websocket.org/",
      pingInterval: Duration(milliseconds: 1000));
  channel.stream.listen(print, onError: print, onDone: () => print('done'));
  Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 3), (t) {
    int time = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
    channel.sink.add("message: hi, $time");
  });
  Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 10), (t) {
    print("closeCode: ${channel.closeCode}");
  });
}
```

And the console output:

```
message: hi, 1562579165221
message: hi, 1562579168221
message: hi, 1562579171221
closeCode: null
message: hi, 1562579174221
message: hi, 1562579177221
message: hi, 1562579180221
closeCode: null    <---- cable pulled
closeCode: null
closeCode: null
```